# Use jComboBox to show certain columns

Tags: java, oop, jtable, jcombobox

This is my code, and it is not working how I want it to.

```
if (jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex() == 0) {
    estateTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setWidth(0);
    estateTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setMinWidth(0);
    estateTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setMaxWidth(0);
}        
if (jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex() == 1) {
    estateTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setWidth(0);
    estateTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setMinWidth(0);
    estateTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setMaxWidth(0);
```

What I want is to display only certain columns on the jTabel but it does not work properly with this code

Comment: Are you revalidating the `JPanel` that contains the `JTable` after changing column widths?

Comment: yes, that's what I'm trying to do

Comment: Edit your question to include a [mre] that we can copy into our IDE, compile, and test.  Otherwise, we're just guessing.